# Radar plot Area Fill - Matlab

Tags: matlab

This is a radar plot script for MATLAB I copied from Google Search.  I was hoping to use radar plot with different scales with 4 or 5 axes.

How would I fill the graph of this radar plot?  Should I use patch or fill?  I know this shouldn't take a long time to do this.  My math isn't that great.

Thanks in advance,
Gary

```
function [f, ca, o] = spider(data,tle,rng,lbl,leg,f)
% create a spider plot for ranking the data
% function [f, ca, o] = spider(data,tle,rng,lbl,leg,f)
%
% inputs  6 - 5 optional
% data    input data (NxM) (# axes (M) x # data sets (N))     class real
% tle     spider plot title                                   class char
% rng     peak range of the data (Mx1 or Mx2)                 class real
% lbl     cell vector axes names (Mxq) in [name unit] pairs   class cell
% leg     data set legend identification (1xN)                class cell
% f       figure handle or plot handle                        class real
%
% outptus 3 - 3 optional
% f       figure handle                                       class integer
% x       axes handle                                         class real
% o       series object handles                               class real
%
% michael arant - jan 30, 2008
%
% to skip any parameter, enter null []
% 
% examples
% 
%   spider([1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12; 13 14 15;16 17 18; ...
%   19 20 21; 22 23 24; 25 26 27]','test plot');
% 
%   spider([1 2 3 4; 4 5 6 7; 7 8 9 10; 10 11 12 13; 13 14 15 16; ...
%   16 17 18 19; 19 20 21 22; 22 23 24 25; 25 26 27 28],'test plot', ...
%   [[0:3:24]' [5:3:29]'],[],{'Case 1' 'Case 2' 'Case 3' 'Case 4'});
% 
%   spider([1 2 3 4; 4 5 6 7; 7 8 9 10; 10 11 12 13; 13 14 15 16; ...
%   16 17 18 19; 19 20 21 22; 22 23 24 25; 25 26 27 28],'test plot', ...
%   [],[],{'Case 1' 'Case 2' 'Case 3' 'Case 4'});
%
%   figure; clf; set(gcf,'color','w'); s = zeros(1,4);
%   for ii = 1:4; s(ii) = subplot(2,2,ii); end
%    
%   spider([1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12; 13 14 15;16 17 18; ...
%   19 20 21; 22 23 24; 25 26 27]','test plot 1',[],[],[],s(1));
% 
%   spider([1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12; 13 14 15;16 17 18; ...
%   19 20 21; 22 23 24; 25 26 27],'test plot 2',[0 30],[],[],s(2));
% 
%   spider([1 2 3 4; 4 5 6 7; 7 8 9 10; 10 11 12 13; 13 14 15 16; ...
%   16 17 18 19; 19 20 21 22; 22 23 24 25; 25 26 27 28]','test plot 3', ...
%   [0 30],{'Label 1' 'Unit 1'; 'Label 2' 'Unit 2'; 'Label 3' 'Unit 3'; ...
%   'Label 4' 'Unit 4'},{'Case 1' 'Case 2' 'Case 3' 'Case 4' 'Case 5' ...
%   'Case 6' 'Case 7' 'Case 8' 'Case 9'},s(3));
% 
%   spider([1 2 3 4; 4 5 6 7; 7 8 9 10; 10 11 12 13; 13 14 15 16; ...
%   16 17 18 19; 19 20 21 22; 22 23 24 25; 25 26 27 28],'test plot 4', ...
%   [[0:3:24]' [5:3:29]'],[],{'Case 1' 'Case 2' 'Case 3' 'Case 4'},s(4));

% data check
if nargin < 1; help spider; error('Need data to plot'); end

% size segments and number of cases
[r c] = size(data);
% exit for too few axes
if r < 3
    errordlg('Must have at least three measuremnt axes')
    error('Program Termination:  Must have a minimum of three axes')
end

% title
if ~exist('tle','var') || isempty(tle) || ~ischar(tle)
    tle = 'Spider Plot';
end

% check for maximum range
if ~exist('rng','var') || isempty(rng) || ~isreal(rng)
    % no range given or range is in improper format
    % define new range
    rng = [min([min(data,[],2) zeros(r,1)],[],2) max(data,[],2)];
    % check for negative minimum values
    if ~isempty(ismember(-1,sign(data)))
        % negative value found - adjust minimum range
        for ii = 1:r
            % negative range for axis ii - set new minimum
            if min(data(ii,:)) < 0
                rng(ii,1) = min(data(ii,:)) - ...
                            0.25 * (max(data(ii,:)) - min(data(ii,:)));
            end
        end
    end
elseif size(rng,1) ~= r
    if size(rng,1) == 1
        % assume that all axes have commom scale
        rng = ones(r,1) * rng;
    else
        % insuffent range definition
        uiwait(msgbox(char('Range size must be Mx1 - number of axes x 1', ...
            sprintf('%g axis ranges defined, %g axes exist',size(rng,1),r))))
        error(sprintf('%g axis ranges defined, %g axes exist',size(rng,1),r))
    end
elseif size(rng,2) == 1
    % assume range is a maximum range - define minimum
    rng = sort([min([zeros(r,1) min(data,[],2) - ...
                        0.25 * (max(data,[],2) - min(data,[],2))],[],2) rng],2);
end

% check for axis labels
if ~exist('lbl','var') || isempty(lbl)
    % no labels given - define a default lable
    lbl = cell(r,1); for ii = 1:r; lbl(ii) = cellstr(sprintf('Axis %g',ii)); end
elseif size(lbl,1) ~= r
    if size(lbl,2) == r
        lbl = lbl';
    else
        uiwait(msgbox(char('Axis labels must be Mx1 - number of axes x 1', ...
            sprintf('%g axis labels defined, %g axes exist',size(lbl,1),r))))
        error(sprintf('%g axis labels defined, %g axes exist',size(lbl,1),r))
    end
elseif ischar(lbl)
    % check for charater labels
    lbl = cellstr(lbl);
end

if ~exist('leg','var') || isempty(leg)
    % no data legend - define default legend
    leg = cell(1,c); for ii = 1:c; leg(ii) = cellstr(sprintf('Set %g',ii)); end
elseif numel(leg) ~= c
    uiwait(msgbox(char('Data set label must be 1XN - 1 x number of sets', ...
        sprintf('%g data sets labeled, %g exist',numel(leg),c))))
    error(sprintf('%g data sets labeled, %g exist',numel(leg),c))
end


% check for figure or axes
if ~exist('f','var')
    % no figure or axes requested - generate new ones
    f = figure; ca = gca(f); cla(ca); hold on; set(f,'color','w')
elseif ismember(f,get(0,'children')')
    % existing figure - clear and set up
    ca = gca(f); hold on;
elseif isint(f)
    % generating a new figure
    figure(f); ca = gca(f); cla(ca); hold on
else
    % may be an axes - may be garbage
    try
        %is this an axes?
        if ismember(get(f,'parent'),get(0,'children')')
            % existing figure axes - use
            ca = f; f = get(f,'parent'); hold on
        end
    catch
        % make new figure and axes
        disp(sprintf('Invalid axes handle %g passed.  Generating new figure',f))
        f = figure; ca = gca(f); cla(ca); hold on
    end
end

% set the axes to the current text axes
axes(ca)
% set to add plot
set(ca,'nextplot','add');

% clear figure and set limits
set(ca,'visible','off'); set(f,'color','w')
set(ca,'xlim',[-1.25 1.25],'ylim',[-1.25 1.25]); axis(ca,'equal','manual')
% title
text(0,1.3,tle,'horizontalalignment','center','fontweight','bold');


% define data case colors
col = color_index(c);


% scale by range
angw = linspace(0,2*pi,r+1)';
mag = (data - rng(:,1) * ones(1,c)) ./ (diff(rng,[],2) * ones(1,c));
% scale trimming
mag(mag < 0) = 0; mag(mag > 1) = 1;
% wrap data (close the last axis to the first)
ang = angw(1:end-1); angwv = angw * ones(1,c); magw = [mag; mag(1,:)];


% make the plot
% define the axis locations
start = [zeros(1,r); cos(ang')]; stop = [zeros(1,r); sin(ang')];
% plot the axes
plot(ca,start,stop,'color','k','linestyle','-'); axis equal
% plot axes markers
inc = 0.25:.25:1; mk = .025 * ones(1,4); tx = 4 * mk; tl = 0:.25:1;
% loop each axis ang plot the line markers and labels
% add axes
for ii = 1:r
    % plot tick marks
    tm = plot(ca,[[cos(ang(ii)) * inc + sin(ang(ii)) * mk]; ...
            [cos(ang(ii)) * inc - sin(ang(ii)) * mk]], ...
            [[sin(ang(ii)) * inc - cos(ang(ii)) * mk] ;
            [sin(ang(ii)) * inc + cos(ang(ii)) * mk]],'color','k');
    % label the tick marks
    for jj = 1:4
%       temp = text([cos(ang(ii)) * inc(jj) + sin(ang(ii)) * tx(jj)], ...
%               [sin(ang(ii)) * inc(jj) - cos(ang(ii)) * tx(jj)], ...
%               num2str(chop(rng(ii,1) + inc(jj)*diff(rng(ii,:)),2)), ...
%               'fontsize',8);
        temp = text([cos(ang(ii)) * inc(jj) + sin(ang(ii)) * tx(jj)], ...
                [sin(ang(ii)) * inc(jj) - cos(ang(ii)) * tx(jj)], ...
                num2str(rd(rng(ii,1) + inc(jj)*diff(rng(ii,:)),-2)), ...
                'fontsize',8);
        % flip the text alignment for lower axes
        if ang(ii) >= pi
            set(temp,'HorizontalAlignment','right')
        end
    end
    % label each axis
    temp = text([cos(ang(ii)) * 1.1 + sin(ang(ii)) * 0], ...
            [sin(ang(ii)) * 1.1 - cos(ang(ii)) * 0], ...
            char(lbl(ii,:)));
    % flip the text alignment for right side axes
    if ang(ii) > pi/2 && ang(ii) < 3*pi/2
        set(temp,'HorizontalAlignment','right')
    end
end


% plot the data
o = polar(ca,angw*ones(1,c),magw);
% set color of the lines
for ii = 1:c; set(o(ii),'color',col(ii,:),'linewidth',1.5); end

% apply the legend
temp = legend(o,leg,'location','best');

return

function [v] = rd(v,dec)
% quick round function (to specified decimal)
% function [v] = rd(v,dec)
%
% inputs  2 - 1 optional
% v       number to round    class real
% dec     decimal loaction   class integer
%
% outputs 1
% v       result             class real
%
% positive dec shifts rounding location to the right (larger number)
% negative dec shifts rounding location to the left (smaller number)
%
% michael arant
% Michelin Maericas Research and Development Corp
if nargin < 1; help rd; error('I/O error'); end

if nargin == 1; dec = 0; end

v = v / 10^dec;
v = round(v);
v = v * 10^dec;

function [val] = color_index(len)
% get unique colors for each item to plot
% function [val] = color_index(len)
%
% inputs  1
% len     number of objects     class integer
%
% outputs 1
% val     color vector          class real
%
% michael arant

if nargin < 1 || nargout < 1; help color_index; error('I / O error'); end

if len == 1
    val = [0 0 0];
else
    % initial color posibilities (no white)
    % default color scale
    col = [ 0 0 0
            0 0 1
            0 1 1
            0 1 0
            1 1 0
            1 0 1
            1 0 0];

    % reduce if fewer than 6 items are needed (no interpolation needed)
    switch len
        case 1, col([2 3 4 5 6 7],:) = [];
        case 2, col([2 3 4 5 6],:) = [];
        case 3, col([3 4 5 6],:) = [];
        case 4, col([3 5 6],:) = [];
        case 5, col([5 6],:) = [];
        case 6, col(6,:) = [];
    end

    % number of requested colors
    val = zeros(len,3); val(:,3) = linspace(0,1,len)';

    % interpolate to fill in colors
    val(:,1) = interp1q(linspace(0,1,size(col,1))',col(:,1),val(:,3));
    val(:,2) = interp1q(linspace(0,1,size(col,1))',col(:,2),val(:,3));
    val(:,3) = interp1q(linspace(0,1,size(col,1))',col(:,3),val(:,3));
end

function [res] = isint(val)
% determines if value is an integer
% function [res] = isint(val)
%
% inputs  1
% val     value to be checked              class real
%
% outputs 1
% res     result (1 is integer, 0 is not)  class integer
%
% michael arant     may 15, 2004
if nargin < 1; help isint; error('I / O error'); end

% numeric?
if ~isnumeric(val); error('Must be numeric'); end

% check for real number
if isreal(val) & isnumeric(val)
%   check for integer
    if round(val) == val
        res = 1;
    else
        res = 0;
    end
else
    res = 0;
end
```

Comment: Copying something from the internet and asking somewhere else "how does this work"  is a terrible way of doing engineering my friend

Comment: I don't know what else to do!  I just want do a radar plot with different scales and the area needs to be filled, because excel doesn't let me have that option.

Comment: Nobody here is going to read 326 lines of random code you found and improve it to your broad specifications, please either learn to code, narrow the scope of this question, or pay somebody elsewhere to write your custom function. I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it is too broad, and doesn't specify the desired behaviour in enough detail (vs the current behaviour) with a [mcve].